# Starting WordPress site on Google Cloud Platform but "error establishing a connection to the database"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress

I am trying to create a WordPress site using Google Cloud Platform. I created the instance and I have everything setup to the point that I have my IP address for the site and have mapped a domain to said IP address. However, the domain name won't actually go to any site and when I try to use the `IP/wp-admin/` to access WordPress I get a `error establishing connection to the database` error message. I have read that it is possibly due to incorrect database credentials in the wp-config file. I am very new to all of this and I'm not sure where to even see that file to check the credentials. Right now, all I have access to is GCP and phpMyAdmin.
Help is appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: More details are required. 1) Is MySQL installed on the same instance as WordPress? 2) Did you set up MySQL? Review steps 1 - 5 in this link. Update your question with details on what you configured. Mask private information such as passwords and IP addresses. https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/ Note: you say that you only have access to phpMyAdmin. You will need to set up SSH access. Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Answer (score 0):

Despite you did not mentioned very clear, I understand that you have an GCP VM instance where you installed WordPress. If this is the case you can read [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) to use it as a guide to edit the wp-config file.

On the other hand, I suggest you [this Google website](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress) as a start point to have initial information about how to build the WordPress website that you need.

I hope this information could be helpful for you.